# How to print rupee sumbol when creating pdf using itext library?

Tags: android, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, cell

i am creaing a pdf using with itext libary but i cant able to print rupee symbol in pdf 
i have string value to print rupee symbol

```
          <string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>
```

and my code to add data in to table is below

```
    PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
    table1.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table1.getDefaultCell().setUseAscender(true);
    PdfPCell cell;
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase((R.string.rs)+"2500",StaticValue.FONT_SUBTITLE));
    cell.setFixedHeight(28);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    table1.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: try <string name="Rs">\u20B9</string>

Comment: you are correct just change R.string.rs to getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);

Comment: @jaimin sorry it doesnt work

Comment: <string name="Rs">₹</string> and then use it.

Comment: What is `StaticValue.FONT_SUBTITLE`? Maybe this font doesn't contain that symbol, or maybe it has an encoding without that symbol...

Answer (score 1):

In your case, maybe the front (StaticValue.FONT_SUBTITLE) does not support the Rupees symbol. So required to use any fonts which support the Rupees Symbol. (For example, fonts such as Lato, Arial, etc.)

Refer the below code snipet,

```
//Rupees symbol
Font rupeesFont = FontFactory.getFont("assets/font"+FONT_NAME, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, FONT_SIZE);
chunkRupee = new Chunk(getString(R.string.rupee_symbol), rupeesFont);
```

Where FONT_NAME is the font in asset->font folder which supports Rupees symbol, FONT_SIZE is the required text size and rupee_symbol is "\u20B9"

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
Chunk chunkContent = new Chunk("Rupees 2500", font);
cell.add(chunkContent);  // your content
cell.add(chunkRupee);  // rupees symbol
table1.addCell(cell);
```